# mod_jk status page not working

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat7, mod-jk

I am doing clustering in Tomcat 7 with Apache server. It is working fine too. However I have the following issues:

1) I am trying to monitor the mod_jk status page; but it is giving 404 error.

2) in Log following error is shown -

```
[Tue Dec 17 13:16:51.019 2013] [2236:140599476504544] [error] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3348): Initializing shm:/etc/httpd/logs/mod_jk.shm.2236 errno=13. Load balancing workers will not function properly.
[Tue Dec 17 13:16:51.019 2013] [2236:140599476504544] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
[Tue Dec 17 13:16:51.041 2013] [2237:140599476504544] [error] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3348): Initializing shm:/etc/httpd/logs/mod_jk.shm.2237 errno=13. Load balancing workers will not function properly.
[Tue Dec 17 13:16:51.042 2013] [2237:140599476504544] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3365): mod_jk/1.2.37 initialized
```

**Here is worker.properties file**

```
worker.list=tomcatnode1,tomcatnode2,loadbalancer,statusmanager

worker.tomcatnode1.port=8009
worker.tomcatnode1.host=localhost
worker.tomcatnode1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatnode1.lbfactor=100

worker.tomcatnode2.port=8010
worker.tomcatnode2.host=localhost
worker.tomcatnode2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcatnode2.lbfactor=100


#Load Balance Configuration
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcatnode1, tomcatnode2
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1

#worker.list=jkstatus
worker.statusmanager.type=status
```

**Here is mod_jk.conf file**

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info
JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm
JkMount /IntellixWebApi/* loadbalancer
#JkMount /jkmanager/* jkstatus
#JkMount /jkmanager jkstatus

<Location /status/>
    JkMount statusmanager
    Order deny,allow
#   Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

If I am accessing IntellixWebApi; it is accessable. but When I am using /status; it is not working.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of googling; I am able to get the jk_manager status screen. Firstly I have disable the SELINUX and then after restarting the system; I set the following JkMount

```
JkMount /* loadbalancer
JkMount /IntellixWebApi/* loadbalancer
JkMount /jkmanager/* jkstatus

<Location /status/>
    JkMount statusmanager
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

This worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kumar, In your worker file, you use `worker.statusmanager.type=status`, but in httpd.conf, you use `JkMount /jkmanager/* jkstatus`, Is it your wrong typing or must do that, because I had disable SELINUX , but still get 404. (my config in httpd.conf use variable the same in worker file).